# Can Spark/EMR read data from s3 multi-threaded

Tags: multithreading, apache-spark, amazon-s3, amazon-emr

Due to some unfortunate sequences of events, we've ended up with a very fragmented dataset stored on s3. The table metadata is stored on Glue, and data is written with "bucketBy", and stored in parquet format. Thus discovery of the files is not an issue, and the number of spark partitions is equal to the number of buckets, which provides a good level of parallelism.

When we load this dataset on Spark/EMR we end up having each spark partition loading around ~8k files from s3.

As we've stored the data in a columnar format; per our use-case where we need a couple of fields, we don't really read all the data but a very small portion of what is stored.

Based on CPU utilization on the worker nodes, I can see that each task (running per partition) is utilizing almost around 20% of their CPUs, which I suspect is due to a single thread per task reading files from s3 sequentially, so lots of IOwait...

Is there a way to encourage spark tasks on EMR to read data from s3 multi-threaded, so that we can read multiple files at the same time from s3 within a task? This way, we can utilize the 80% idle CPU to make things a bit faster?

Comment: Generally, one vcpu can run only 1 thread per task. If you want to run multiple threads per task, you need to set this variable: spark.task.cpu which is by default 1 and then you need to do parallelism inside your code which will run on executor.

Comment: And here is one link explaining why cpu is not being utilized much while doing IO, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13596997/why-is-the-cpu-not-needed-to-service-i-o-requests

Comment: I think I can do such an operation on RDD level, however I'm working on the Dataset/Dataframe API level, thus I will need an underlying level to read files multi-threaded... Unless I end up re-implementing Dataframes from scratch with multi-threading built in ;)

Comment: Then you need to create multiple executors which can read data in parallel. It totally depends how you write the code.

Comment: I didn’t really understand what you meant by this. Can you give an example?

Comment: Can you provide more detail what and how you was doing? so I can think of something.

Answer (score 2):

There are two parts to reading S3 data with Spark dataframes:

1. Discovery (listing the objects on S3)
2. Reading the S3 objects, including decompressing, etc.

Discovery typically happens on the driver. Some managed Spark environments have optimizations that use cluster resources for faster discovery. This is not typically a problem unless you get beyond 100K objects. Discovery is slower if you have `.option("mergeSchema", true)` as each file will have to touched to discover its schema.

Reading S3 files is part of executing an action. The parallelism of reading is min(number of partitions, number of available cores). More partitions + more available cores means faster I/O... in theory. In practice, S3 can be quite slow if you haven't accesses these files regularly for S3 to scale their availability up. Therefore, in practice, additional Spark parallelism has diminishing returns. Watch the total network RW bandwidth per active core and tune your execution for the highest value.

You can discover the number of partitions with `df.rdd.partitions.length`.

There are additional things you can do if the S3 I/O throughput is low:

1. Make sure the data on S3 is dispersed when it comes to its prefix (see https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/optimizing-performance.html).
2. Open an AWS support request and ask the prefixes with your data to be scaled up.
3. Experiment with different node types. We have found storage-optimized nodes to have better effective I/O.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Hi @Sim, What I'm asking is, per task how to read in multiple thread (if possible). The problem I want to solve is, per task (i.e. per partition) it's only utilizing around 20% CPU and the IOWait is due to reading the data from s3.

Comment: @zetaprime there is no way to do this natively with Spark at this time. It fundamentally violates the processing model. Some managed Spark environments have caching optimizations that do pre-fetch operations from S3 to local worker or faster network storage, achieving an effect similar to what you desire. Independently, how can you be certain that the bottleneck is not on S3 or on the local physical hardware/network? The only way to test this is to change Spark parallelism and see what happens.

Comment: I can clearly see when I check the workers’ threads and see the threads waiting on socket read while requesting data from s3.

Comment: @zetaprime I understand. My answer stands: unless you write custom code to process your data and only use Spark for parallel code execution, there is no way to increase parallelism without increasing worker cores or using a managed Spark provider with a smart caching layer.

Comment: how many workers per process do you have? Make sure that the s3a settings for threads and http connections is bigger than that, so those pools don't become the bottleneck. Otherwise, small files are expensive everywhere, worse on S3 because of the overheads. Can you coalesce them before doing anything else?